# Regex to check parentheses for C code

Tags: regex, linux

I am quite new to regex, and I use them only for searching. So I play around with egrep, but with egrep I see some limitations.

For linux are there any good tool for regex? I know there is sed but its usually used in scenarios to search and replace. Can I used sed only to search through my files ? If yes how ?

Coming to my specific question, I need to search for instances in C source code where additional parentheses are used for `if` statements.

`if (( a == b))` should match and `if (a == b)` should not match.
`if(a && ((b||c)))` should match and `if(a && (b||c))` should not match.

I want it to be simple, I will add additional cases later like `>=` `!=` etc.

Comment: This is not possible with regexes (at least not on their own), as they cannot keep track of arbitrary levels of nesting of parentheses.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth, you should make that an answer, at it is *the* answer.

Comment: Ok, wat about sed as search tool and not search and replace ??

Comment: @JeremyStein: I have made it so!  My initial hesitation was because normally a "good answer" should be accompanied with a recommendation of what to do instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not possible with regexes (at least not on their own), as they cannot keep track of arbitrary levels of nesting of parentheses.

Comment: To add to this answer, be careful attempting this even outside of regex. The only (practical) way to ensure you're detecting a truly "unnecessary" set of parentheses, is to see a double-open closed by a double-close, e.g. ``(( ... ))``. A non-regex-only solution might search for ``/\(\s*\(/``, then read char by char, counting levels, until a closing parenthesis is found at level 0, and here if we match ``/\)\s*\)/``, then we _might_ know it's a redundant pair of parentheses--barring of course things we didn't anticipate, e.g. a stray parenthesis or emoticon in a comment ;)